# MySQL: Getting duplicate values when connecting multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to connect multiple tables to one very big table

```
  SELECT * FROM
  Person, Patient, vanster_implantat,
  hoger_implantat, vanster_operationer, 
  hoger_operationer, vanster_processorpatient, 
  hoger_processorpatient, processor
```

This gives a lot of duplicate values because there is no connections to eachother. I want all tables to be somehow connected to the table 'Patient' by the column 'nummer' in which all tables have. I tried to connect all the tables to the table 'Patient' at the same time like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM
Person, Patient, vanster_implantat, hoger_implantat, vanster_operationer, hoger_operationer, vanster_processorpatient, hoger_processorpatient WHERE
person.nummer = patient.nummer AND
patient.nummer = vanster_implantat.nummer AND
patient.nummer = hoger_implantat.nummer AND
patient.nummer = vanster_operationer.nummer AND
patient.nummer = hoger_operationer.nummer AND 
patient.nummer = vanster_processorpatient.nummer AND
patient.nummer = hoger_processorpatient.nummer
```

But this result in No Data because it either HAS to be connected to ALL the tables OR it shows nothing at all. It's a all or nothing situation. What I want it to show the connection it currently has with the other tables, it may one connection or more. I hope you understood what I meant and I appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: i think you need joins: [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select
    *
from
    patient
left join
    person on person.nummer = patient.nummer
left join
    vanster_implantat on vanster_implantat.nummer = patient.nummer
left join
    hoger_implantat on hoger_implantat.nummer = patient.nummer
left join
    vanster_operationer on vanster_operationer.nummer = patient.nummer
left join
    hoger_operationer on hoger_operationer.nummer = patient.nummer
left join
    vanster_processorpatient on vanster_processorpatient.nummer = patient.nummer
left join
    hoger_processorpatient on hoger_processorpatient.nummer = patient.nummer;
```

This is a left outer join with the main driving table being `patient`. It basically means that if the others tables don't have the join then it'll still be ok. You can remove `left` on some of the joins if you want to make sure there is a matching record in that table.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to `JOIN` the tables `ON` the foreign key representing the `Patient`.
Ie something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Patient as pa LEFT JOIN Person as pe ON pe.nummer = pa.nummer
```

Go read up on the different `JOIN` clauses to see exactly what you need, you'll also want to take a look at clauses like `GROUP BY`. I second the comments for you to learn the basics of SQL before using it, it is a headache to learn that through trail & error.